# この質問はどのあたりの詳細があれば答えやすくなりますか？

Tags: 討議, 質問のクローズ

先日「[Express,socket.ioを利用したリアルタイムの投票系webアプリケーションについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/54518/19110)」という質問が「質問内容がはっきりしない」としてクローズされました。

わたしはこの分野に詳しくないため、どのあたりの質問内容がはっきりしないのかよく分かりませんでした :-( コメントも無かったため、どこを改善すれば再オープンされるのか知りたいなと思いました。

こちらのご質問はどのあたりを編集すれば質問内容が明瞭になるでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

実現したいことの仕様がはっきりしているなら、まずは自分で試してみて、その上で**躓いた部分に対しての質問**をするべきなのかなと個人的には思いました。

同じ様に「仕様ははっきりしてるのに、どこに躓いてるのかがはっきりしない」と感じられる質問を時々見かけます。
直近だと以下の質問などで、こちらもクローズ票を集めてしまっています。

[vue で音付きタイマーの実装](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/54544/3060)

Comment: 最初の一歩すら分からないときは、そのことも書いておいた方が分かりやすいでしょうか。

Comment: その場合は「最初の一歩」がまず解決すべき課題ではありませんか？そしてそれが「プログラミング言語の書き方が分からない」から始まるようなら、QAサイトで扱う質問としては範囲が広すぎると思います。